# using localdatetime in tornadofx with rest springboot

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, tornadofx

i develop a tornadofx app with springboot rest service as backend
all  in kotlin language

the problem is tornadofx seNd LocalDateTime as Int
this cause this error in springboot server

```
2018-01-31 18:33:31.296  WARN 11473 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string.; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string.
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 16] (through reference chain: andalous.torndadoserver.financial.dailymove.newDailyMove["date"])
```

i add to springboot but can't solve

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and using this in application.properties

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to serialize the json data any way you like. Instead of doing `json.add("key", someLocalDateTimeValue)` you can do `json.add("key", someLocalDataTimeValueConvertedToWhateverFormatYouWant)`. You could even add an extension function to make it nice to work with.

That said, it should be pretty easy to come up with a configurable option for how to store LocalDateTime in the built in JsonBuilder. A PR would be most welcome :)

Comment: thank youfor intersting ,in sample way i use LocalDateTime.toString() and it work

Answer (score 1):

this is working in perfect way with tornadofx

```
override fun toJSON(json: JsonBuilder) {
    with(json){
        add("date",date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))
    }
}

override fun updateModel(json: JsonObject) {
    with(json){
        date= LocalDateTime.parse(string("date"),DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    }
}
```